# Playsound Module in python

Tags: python, module, compiler-errors, playsound

I am not able to run a audio file automatically when the program started i saw playsound module but it is giving me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    playsound('Music/videoplayback(2).mp3')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

my code

```
import random
import playsound
#Creating a KBC Special Quiz!
print("'\033[1m'"+"Welcome To Kaun Banega Crorepati!")
print()
print()
playsound('Music/videoplayback(2).mp3')
```

i am using repl, even i am finding difficulties in pathing

Comment: You have to use something within the `playsound` module. You may want to use `playsound.playsound` or import it like this `from playsound import playsound`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `playsound` module instead of the `playsound.playsound` function.

The [docs](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) show you how to import it so it works like you expected, see below.

```
>>> from playsound import playsound
>>> playsound('/path/to/a/sound/file/you/want/to/play.mp3')
```